# jQuery Mobile, HTML5, setting input field of type="date"

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I am using jQuery mobile 1.1.0. I have a form where the user can edit information. In that form are 2 fields with date values. Since I want to leverage the built in date picker functionality, the input type is set to "date". When the form loads on a desktop browser the value is set properly with a date, however when I view the same form on my mobile device (iPhone iOS 5), the date fields are not populated.

Below is one field, with the type="text". The value gets set fine:

```
<input type="text" id="name"  />

$("#name").val(obj.Name);
```

The date field (type="date") never gets a value set:

```
<input type="date" id="startdate" />

$("#startdate").val(obj.StartDate);
```

As stated, on a desktop browser (Chrome/Firefox), the fields get a value set. It's on the Safari mobile that it doesn't.

If this has already been answered somewhere please excuse me! I've searched but haven't found anything related.

Comment: I found the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183959/setting-the-value-of-date-inputs-on-ipad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer from another post: [Setting the value of date inputs on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183959/setting-the-value-of-date-inputs-on-ipad)

It's simply a matter of formatting the date to yyyy-MM-dd, it's that simple.