# Setting the value of date inputs on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, mobile-safari

**WEB APP** not native, no Objective-C

This is so simple it hurts.

```
  <input type="date" />
```

Done to use the iPad native datepicker. Then setting the initial value with jQuery

```
  $('input[type="date"]').val('Jun 25, 2012');
```

Resulting in an empty input field. The jQuery above works great in ie7-9, chrome, safari, and FF, but not in iOS!

I am out of ideas. Does anyone know a work around? Or why this happens?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.  I as trying to populate it with 6/25/2012, but 2012-06-25 is what was required.

Comment: @Phillip if you liked this question, and upvote is always appreciated :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this for Safari on iOS 5

```
 $('input[type="date"]').val('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

You could do the conversion from the type of Date you are using to `yyyy-MM-DD` in JavaScript using the `Date()` function.

Comment: what if that is not the date format I am looking for. Also, why?

Comment: I think the other formats don't work reliably. So I'd suggest you do the conversion in JavaScript using the Date() function. Since iOS5, there are other inputs as well. Detailed at http://shareourideas.com/2011/10/29/ios-5-and-html5-input-types/

Comment: Holy bloody F#$#$. I tried this and the ipad accepted the input change, AND REFORMATTED IT ITSELF!

Comment: Using `new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)` on iOS here.

Comment: I was using `attr` to no avail, but `val` works great.

Answer (score 7):

for iOS6 the ISO format "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ" is required:

```
var now = new Date().toISOString();
$("input[type=datetime]").val(now);
```

Comment: You are my hero. This solution works in an ionic application for those that need to know.