# type of object returned from Mobile Safari date input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios6, datepicker, mobile-safari

I'm trying to figure out what kind of object Mobile Safari returns when I use the built-in date picker. For example:

```
<input id="d" type="date" />
```

And the javascript:

```
alert( $("#d").val() );
```

On non-Mobile Safari platforms, this returns the date (eg. "01/30/2013"). On Mobile Safari, I think this returns absolutely nothing. I found this article ([Setting the value of date inputs on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183959/setting-the-value-of-date-inputs-on-ipad)) that got me somewhere a little further:

```
alert( $("#d").val('yyyy-MM-dd') );
```

But the alert pops up `[object Object]` and I'm stuck. What kind of object is it returning when I specify a format in the `val()` selector? I've tried running it through $.datepicker (from jQueryUI) but that didn't work, and when I try `new Date($("#d").val('yyyy-MM-dd'))` the alert that comes back says "Invalid date." Ultimately all I want is to take the "Jan 30, 2013" string that the date field returns and turn it into "01/30/2013" (a string) so I can pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` has two functions - w/o param it's a getter and returns a date and with 1 param it's a setter and returns the dom-object you were calling the `.val()` on. So if you call `alert( $("#d").val('yyyy-MM-dd') );` actually the alert returns you the `#d` dom-object.

This also is the reason why `new Date($("#d").val('yyyy-MM-dd'))` gives you an error. It instead should read:  `new Date($("#d").val('yyyy-MM-dd').val())`.

```
new Date("Jan 30, 2013")
```

should work fine for all but for IOS you need

```
new Date("2013-01-30")
```

This returns you a Date object which you then can work with.

The method `.toISOString();` helps you converting a normal Date to the by IOS required ISO format.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Safari returns exactly the same type of value for a date input as any other Webkit browser. The confusion you're having is with jQuery.

jQuery's val method returns the value of the date input's 'value' property when called without parameters, e.g.

```
var value = $("input.foo").val()
```

But when it's called /with/ parameters it will set the value property and return a jQuery object to allow for chaining. e.g.

```
var value = $("input.foo").val("2013-05-22").val() //"2013-05-22"
```

In the last example the value is set to "2013-05-22", and then read.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be human error. The mobile version was trying to read the wrong input. (One desktop input with a jQueryUI picker on a `<input type="text">` field, and one mobile input with a `<input type="date">` field.)

I feel like such an idiot...turns out all you need is `<input type="date">` and even though Mobile Safari will put "Jan 31, 2013" in the field, jQuery 1.9 `$("#d").val()` returns "2013-01-31" without any tricks. Assuming, of course, you're reading the right input field.